# How to select between with values from other table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, between

I have two query:

1. Select * from table1 where my_value between value1 and value2;
2. Select value1, value2 from table2;

And the sets of value1 and value2 in table2 is unique. 
How can I plugin all result sets of query 2 in where statements of the first query ?

```
Resolved: Using exists key:
select *
from t1
where exists
(
    select *
    from t2
    where t1.my_value between t2.value1 and t2.value2
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want records from table 1 for which *exist* a match in table 2, `EXISTS` seems straight-forward:

```
select *
from t1
where exists
(
  select *
  from t2
  where t1.my_value between t2.value1 and t2.value2
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.myvalue BETWEEN t2.value1 AND t2.value2
```

Comment: It duplicates result rows, though, when ranges can overlap, e.g. myvalue = 3; t2 record #1 = 1->4; t2 record #2 = 2->5.